# How to provide linespace beween two logger messages?

Tags: log4j

In my case,

I am able to see my logger messages without line spaces.I dont know so much about the layout and patterns of log4j.

my log4j.xml is::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}    %-5l     - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <errorHandler class="org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler" />
    <param name="File" value="E:/hib808.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="20000KB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="400" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %d{dd MMM yyyy    HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5l - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- Application Loggers -->
<logger name="mkcl.oesclient.controllers">
    <level value="error" />


</logger>

<!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
<logger name="org.springframework.core">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.beans">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.context">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.web">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="error" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />

</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

my output is like this::

ERROR: 22 Aug 201310:11:50.674mkcl.oesclient.utilities.TestToGenerateException.getException
ERROR: 22 Aug 2013 10:11:55.194 mkcl.oesclient.controllers xyz

I have to provide a linespace between these messages.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,
Changed the **ConversionPattern** 
initilay it was **%-5p: %d{dd MMM yyyy    HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5l - %m%n**

change it to 
**%-5p: %d{dd MMM yyyy    HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5l - %m%n%n**

that is i have added one more line separator %n inmy pattern.